# How to have 2 Models/Views/Templates on one Page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I know this has probably been asked a 1000 times but I still for the life of me can't find a decent answer. Reading tutorials, Stack and even looking at GitHub for examples - nothing is helping or even guiding me in the right direction.

I have 2 separate Models/Views/Templates which each work beautifully on their own URLS.

I want these Models/Views/Templates to work on a single URL ie

```
url(r'^$', 'chrometask.views.index', name='home'),
```

(ie my homepage.)

How??? This seems to be way overly complicated for such a simple ask.

here is my views.py

```
items = Task.objects.all()
form = TaskForm(request.POST or None)
task_list = Task.objects.order_by('priority')
context_dict = { 'Tasks' : task_list}

if form.is_valid():
    save_it = form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('') 

return render_to_response('home.html', #Don't know how to render 2 html files or add the context_dict
                          locals(),
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

render_to_resonse can only take 3 arguments, and when I put the table inside 'home.html' with {% blockquote %} it wont show on the page.

```
 <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-hardware-laptop-"></i>Title</a></div>
  <div class="collapsible-body">
  <div class="intro grey lighten-5">

    {% block content %}{% endblock %} <--This is the table.html, which extends fine with {% entends 'home.html' %}-->

</br>
```

Please don't direct me to tutorials, These haven't resolved the issue, I would rather you spelt it out in layman's terms if possible, this may help drill the answer into my thick skull.

note - I am New to Django.

(*apologies for the frankness - this is really beginning to drive me up the wall)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what you have tried to do to solve this, why you think it's "way overly complicated", or why it's causing you frustration.

The thing to understand is that a view is entirely responsible for a page, ie the view creates the entire response when a URL is requested. You can't have two views on a URL; that simply doesn't make sense.

But the other thing to understand is that templates and models are *not* in any way connected to any particular view. One view can render any number of templates, one, many, or even none; and any of those templates can involve any number of models from any number of apps.

So, if you wanted to include tasks in your home page, one approach is just to include the `Tasks` in the context dictionary in your view, and include the relevant code to your template to display them.

Now, if you're doing this in multiple views, then clearly you want to put that code somewhere sensible so that you Don't Repeat Yourself. The ideal place for this is an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags): you can wrap up the code that queries the latest tasks, and the template fragment that renders them, into a single tag which you can then use on your home page template.

**Edit**

The context is the second argument to `render_to_response`: the place where you've currently put `locals()`. That's a horrible pattern which I hate, and which is confusing you unnecessarily. Instead of using locals, put all the things you require for the context specifically into `context_dict` and pass that there instead.

(Also note you should use the `render` shortcut rather than `render_to_response`, which accepts the request as the first parameter and doesn't need all that mucking around with RequestContext.)

```
context_dict = { 'Tasks' : task_list, 'form': form}
...
return render(request, 'home.html', context_dict)
```

The code you have posted for your template is confusing. Is the table in table.html or home.html? If you pass "home.html" in your call to `render`, then it's home.html that will be rendered, not table. If you want to render table so that it extends home, then pass "table.html" in your call to render.

Comment: OK, you need to show that code so we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have tried almost every method on stack overflow with no luck, and the more I read examples the more it becomes even more complicated. I have put 2 models inside a view, only one renders, I write both html into one html file, only one renders, I have tried ListView only one renders, I am going round in circles with this, again like I said I am new to Django, my thing I want to now is how to put both/Multiple on one page, regardless of type.

Comment: Well I seriously can't help you unless you **post the code**. If you send the relevant data from the view to the template, and the template contains the relevant code to render both bits of data, then it will work, and this has nothing to do with "rendering two" of anything.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I really don't know what else I can show, The code I have posted previously is where I've got to, I'd like to find out how I can have both 'home and 'TaskList' on the same page, both work on separate URLs,

Comment: But you *just said* you'd tried "putting two models inside a view" and "writing both html into one file". You haven't shown either of those approaches here. Both should work, but since you haven't posted the code where you tried it, I can't tell you what you did wrong. And I explained in full in my question how you would get two pieces of content on one page.

Comment: done - any ideas what I can do, where I should go next

Comment: Got it working, wow what a mess that was, phew. so Instead of creating 2 views for 2 models I create 1 View and call that? Ok I get it now, So I add x number of models to the context_dict? and use render instead of render_to_rsponse? Thank you, Thank you, Thank you. I have been following tutorials online hence the lack of adaptibility in my code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

My Code ended up looking like

```
def home(request):

items = Task.objects.all()
form = TaskForm(request.POST or None)
task_list = Task.objects.order_by('priority')

context_dict = { 'Tasks' : task_list, 'form': form}

if form.is_valid():
    save_it = form.save()
    save_it.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')

return render(request, 'table.html', context_dict)
```

This has both models workig in one view.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tutlist(request,tut):
    model = Tutorial
    model = Codetut
    template_name = 'backpages/tutorial.html'
    temp = Parts.objects.get(pk = tut)
    model = temp.tutorial_set.all()
    print(model)
    temp = Parts.objects.get(pk = tut)
    code = temp.codetut_set.all()
    print(code)
    context = {'model' : model ,'something': code}
    return render(request, template_name,context)
```

i was having a similar problem i wanted to display two different views on a single template with a single url so i did something like this which worked well for me.